# display images when mouseover in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i have four action link with employeeid.when user clicks the action link it shows the employee details.
now i want to display employee image when mouse over the action link.
can anyone tell how to implement this in asp.net mvc 2.0.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#employeeid').hover(function(){
    var id=$('#employeeid').val();
    alert(id);
    $('#images').attr('src',$(this).attr('id'));
     //$("#images").attr("src", "/Home/ShowEmployeeImage/" + id);
     $('#images').show();
 },
 function(){
     $('#images').hide();
 });

})
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an extra `});` in the end, remove that

Comment: @PedroEstrada really? i didn't know that, what is the new standar?

Comment: `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`

Comment: anyone tell some links or websites for this

Comment: yes @Marsh i'll help you in out in a second

Comment: @PedroEstrada where i can find the deprecated functions for jquery?

Comment: @Marsh http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: @PedroEstrada but in that page hover() doesnt appears as deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra `});` in your code, right after the second handler for your `.hover()` remove that and it should work.

But to make everything work in the long run, i suggest changing your code slightly.

instead of `.attr()` you should use `.prop()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#employeeid').hover(function(){
    var id=$('#employeeid').val();
    alert(id);
    $('#images').prop('src', id);
    //$("#images").prop("src", "/Home/ShowEmployeeImage/" + id);
    $('#images').show();
  }, function(){
    $('#images').hide();
  });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle using random data but showing you how to use them: http://jsfiddle.net/bzzzJ/2/

Comment: where did you found the function hover() is deprecated?. This is not mentioned in api.jquery.com/category/deprecated

Comment: i was researching and I found  [.on("hover"...)] is deprecated, not .hover(). Source: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11731#comment:4

Comment: @MichaelAguilar You are absolutely correct, i think i mistook `.hover()` for `.toggle()` i apologize